# Asterisk (“*”) expansion as filenames for a IFORT program

Tags: fortran, arguments, command, gfortran

I am trying to do something with some files of same filename pattern, e.g:

```
data1.dat
data2.dat
data3.dat
...
datan.dat
```

with

```
program readoneline
character(1024)               :: line, filename
integer :: i, nfile, ifile

nfile = command_argument_count()
do i = 1, nfile
  call get_command_argument(i, filename)
  open(newunit=ifile, file=trim(filename)
  read(ifile, '(A)') line
  print*, 'Fist line of'//trim(filename)//' is 'trim(line)
end do
```

In Windows, if I compile it with Gfortran 8 (comes with rtools), it will expand asterisk (“*”) below to all files:

```
gfortran -cpp -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-none -O2 -static -s readoneline.f90 -o readoneline
readoneline.exe data*.dat
```

However, if I compile it with ifort (Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.5.0 Build 20211109_000000),

```
ifort -traceback -heap-arrays -O2 -fpe:0 -fpp -nowarn -nologo -static readoneline.f90 -o readoneline
readoneline.exe data*.dat
```

it will read command line argument verbosely as "data*.dat".

How can I make ifort behave like gfortran? I want to use ifort because it's faster than gfortran.

worked

```
gfortran -cpp -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-none -O2 -static -s readoneline.f90 -o readoneline
readoneline.exe data*.dat
```

not worked

```
ifort -traceback -heap-arrays -O2 -fpe:0 -fpp -nowarn -nologo -static readoneline.f90 -o readoneline
readoneline.exe data*.dat
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? And please show more detail on the output you see.

Comment: Maybe start Windows powershell, then .\readoneline.exe (Get-ChildItem .\data*.dat | Select-Object -Expand FullName)

Comment: Although it might be easier and more portable just to dump all the file names to file with dir data*.dat /b > filename and then read that file, rather than using command-line arguments.

Comment: It is really up to the shell to expand any wildcards. Are you sure you tested both versions in the same shell?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I would expect any classical unix shell to expand the `*`, but whether it expand or not, it has to be consistent and either always expand or never expand. If the reported commands here are the right ones, then it can't be the same shell with the same configuration.

Comment: I don't know rtools at all, but it comes with `bash` as the default shell. So I suspect that the gfortran case is run in `bash`, and the ifort case is run in the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.

Comment: Windows shells don’t expand wildcards like unix shells; it is, unfortunately, up to individual applications to do it. If the commands are run in windows cmd.exe then both gfortran and ifort behave exactly as the OP says.

Comment: @francescalus: Both are tested in the same CMD shell and also on different Windows computers (some without rtools installed).

Comment: @lastchance, I think `data*.dat /b > filename` could be a way around it.

Comment: @PierU they were ran in the same CMD cell. even on different Windows computers (some without rtools installed). The specific path I call gfortran is `C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe`.